# Spring Roo: JDBC driver not available for 'org.h2.Driver'

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-roo, h2

I'm running Eclipse Indigo on Ubuntu Linux, Spring Tools 2.7.1, Spring Roo 1.1.5. I'm reading [Getting Started with Roo](http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/Getting_Started_with_Roo.pdf) and when I try the DB reverse engineering I've the following error:

```
roo> database reverse engineer --schema ROO_CRM --package org.obliquid.crm.domain
Located add-on that may offer this JDBC driver
 1 found, sorted by rank; T = trusted developer; R = Roo 1.1 compatible
ID T R DESCRIPTION -------------------------------------------------------------
01 Y Y 1.3.159.0001 H2 #jdbcdriver driverclass:org.h2.Driver. This bundle...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[HINT] use 'addon info id --searchResultId ..' to see details about a search result
[HINT] use 'addon install id --searchResultId ..' to install a specific search result, or
[HINT] use 'addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName TAB' to install a specific add-on version
JDBC driver not available for 'org.h2.Driver'
```

However, even if I try with

```
roo> addon install id --searchResultId 01
```

running again the reverse engineer causes the same error. In my pom.xml I've also this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.155</version>
    <classifier />
</dependency>
```

How to resolve the impasse?

**UPDATE**: In my subsequent tests, I converted the DB to MySQL and while in eclipse it was still not working, in the standalone roo shell it worked. However, I'm now at home while today I was at work, so it may also be a network issue. I suspect that it would also work with H2 now.

```
roo> addon install id --searchResultId 1
Target resource(s):
------------------                                                     
   Spring Roo - Wrapping - mysql-connector-java (5.1.17.0020)

Required resource(s):  
---------------------                                                    
   slf4j-api (1.6.1)                     
   slf4j-nop (1.6.1)       

Deploying...done.                                                    

Successfully installed add-on: Spring Roo - Wrapping - mysql-connector-java [version: 5.1.17.0020] 
[Hint] Please consider rating this add-on with the following command:                                                                         
[Hint] addon feedback bundle --bundleSymbolicName org.springframework.roo.wrapping.mysql-connector-java --rating ... --comment "..."
```

**UPDATE 2**: Again for another sample project reverse engineer worked in the standalone shell, but didn't work within Eclipse. So for now my workaround is issue reverse engineering in the standalone roo shell.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Eclipse network settings. It could often become problematic if you are behind a proxy server.